# Fetch data from multiple tables Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

hello I have four tables and I am trying to fetch data from all of them. 
Tables are

1. User
2. UserInfo
3. Category
4. UserCategory

Since user can select multiple categories so I have setup a separate table called `UserCategory`. This table has `user_id` and `cat_id` as foreign key of `user` and `Category` Table fields

In `Category` Table, the field is `cat_name`

I want to get  All the data from all the four tables associated with the particular userID. So at the moment I have achieved this. I'll show you how.

```
class UserInfo extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'user_info';
    public $primaryKey = 'user_id';


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'type' => 'RIGHT',
            'fields' => array('User.user_id','User.email','User.active')
        )


    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'UserCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'UserCategory',
            'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => array('user_id = UserCategory.user_id')
            //'order' => 'UserCategory. DESC'
        ),


    );
    public function getUserDetails($user_id){
        return $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserInfo.user_id' => $user_id
            ),


        ));

    }
```

By doing this

```
$userDetails = $this->UserInfo->getUserDetails($user_id);
```

I get a result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UserInfo] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 9
                    [first_name] => lorem
                    [last_name] => ipsum
                    [phone_no] => 123
                    [profile_img] => app/webroot/uploads/9/589c538daa276test.png.png
                    [registration_date] => 2017-02-09 08:33:33
                    [device_token] => ddd222
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 9
                    [email] => new email
                    [active] => 1
                )

            [UserCategory] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user_category_id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 9
                            [cat_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user_category_id] => 3
                            [user_id] => 9
                            [cat_id] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [user_category_id] => 4
                            [user_id] => 9
                            [cat_id] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to know how Can I get Category names from category table in the above array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [containable](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) in this case:

```
public function getUserDetails($user_id) {
    $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'UserInfo.user_id' => $user_id
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'User', 'UserCategory.Category'
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: glad to help :)